# Unable to install wine on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wine

I followed the instruction I got from winehq here "https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu". But when I run "sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable", I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 8.0.0.0~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and I get this error if I try to install from the staging or development branches:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-[devel/staging] : Depends: wine-[devel/staging] (= 8.2~jammy-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also noticed that if I try to run "sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-[any branch]", I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgphoto2-6:i386 : Depends: libgd3:i386 (>= 2.1.0~alpha~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and if I try to install "libgd3:i386", apt ends up removing "libgd3", "colord" which then causes gnome-control-center to be removed too. Seems "libgd3" and "libgd3:i386" can't be installed simultaneously.

Any chance I can still install any version of wine on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Try installing just `wine` from the default Ubuntu repos.  It should install `wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)`

Comment: @Terrance It is installed but I get the message "it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it." when I try to use it (by running the "wine" command).

Comment: I'm not in front of my system right now, but you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371617/wine32-is-missing-issue-in-ubunt-20-04-as-root-please-execute-apt-get-insta if it might help you.